# Entity Framework intermittently set the byte field into 255

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a piece of code that inserts into a table. Simply, I have a table with structure

**Table1**:

- Id  int PK
- Type tinyint
- Status tinyint

After digging in our PROD, I observed that EF might be intermittently defaulting the value to 255 when the value should range (1-3). I understand 255 is the max value for tinyint in SQL Server but I have no defaults in both table definition and in EDMX.

Usage:

```
//OUTAGE_TYPE
public enum OUTAGE_TYPE
{
        Unknown = -1,
        SwitchingPlan = 1,
        PlannedIncident = 2,
        UnplannedIncident = 3
}

//CREATE INSTANCE
var outage = new Outage
        {
            OutageTypeId = (byte)OUTAGE_TYPE.SwitchingPlan,
            OutageStatusId = (byte)OUTAGE_STATUS.Approved,
            IncidentRID = incident.RID,
            WorkRID = incident.WorkRID,
            ETR = incident.ETR,
            DateInserted = Time.Now(),
            DateUpdated = Time.Now()
        };
```

Captured SQL:

```
INSERT [dbo].[Outage]([OutageTypeId], [OutageStatusId], [IncidentRID], [WorkRID], [ETR], [DateInserted], [DateUpdated])
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, NULL, @3, @4, @5)
SELECT [Id]
FROM [dbo].[Outage]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [Id] = scope_identity()
-- @0: '255' (Type = Byte, Size = 1)
-- @1: '1' (Type = Byte, Size = 1)
-- @2: 'INC 11000700' (Type = String, Size = 255)
-- @3: '05-08-2016 10:05:52' (Type = DateTime2)
-- @4: '05-08-2016 22:05:22' (Type = DateTime2)
-- @5: '05-08-2016 22:05:22' (Type = DateTime2)
-- Executing at 06-08-2016 00:06:00 +02:00
```

Error:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Outage_OutageType". The conflict occurred in database "ONSP", table "dbo.OutageType", column 'Id'.

I was not able to reproduce on my local machine, maybe you guys have experienced this before. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After my colleague and me digging around, we found the root cause of this problem.
First -1, is not a valid value for a byte and direct conversion will not throw exception but will yield to byte.MaxValue

```
void Main()
{
    var type = OUTAGE_TYPE.Unknown;
    var result = (byte)type;

    //result = 255!!!
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}

public enum OUTAGE_TYPE
{
       Unknown = -1,
       SwitchingPlan = 1,
       PlannedIncident = 2,
       UnplannedIncident = 3
}
```

Comment: Your question had `Unknown = 0` in it. Hopefully now you know to include *actual* code in the question: based on your original question, there was no way anyone could have answered. But good that you edited the question and provided a good answer that could possibly help others having the same problem.

Comment: yes, it was Uknown = 0 in the original post, because I copied the code from the current branch, and not from the release branch in our PROD. sorry for that.